# passing Stripe token to Firebase (obj-c)

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, stripe-payments

I have deployed a cloud function to my Firebase In order to use Firebase as my backend server to handle Stripe payment.
The link of the sample Firebase cloud functions i have used: https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/stripe

Here is the function I should trigger when I charge the user in my app

```
exports.createStripeCharge = functions.database.ref('/stripe_customers/{userId}/charges/{id}').onWrite((event) => {
  const val = event.data.val();


  if (val === null || val.id || val.error) return null;

  return admin.database().ref(`/stripe_customers/${event.params.userId}/customer_id`).once('value').then((snapshot) => {
    return snapshot.val();
  }).then((customer) => {

    const amount = val.amount;
    const idempotency_key = event.params.id;
    let charge = {amount, currency, customer};
    if (val.source !== null) charge.source = val.source;
    return stripe.charges.create(charge, {idempotency_key});
  }).then((response) => {

    return event.data.adminRef.set(response);
  }).catch((error) => {


    return event.data.adminRef.child('error').set(userFacingMessage(error));
  }).then(() => {
    return reportError(error, {user: event.params.userId});
  });
});
```

I know that the above function will be triggered when my database changed. 
My question is, what is the proper way to pass the Stripe payment detail to my Firebase Database? I am not sure what should I pass to my firebase database after reading the stripe document.

Could anyone help me with this question? Thanks!!

P.S. My developing environment: Objective C, IOS application.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to have your app make an HTTP POST request to an [HTTP Firebase function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events). Your app should already be doing this in order to create the Stripe ephemeral key and you can handle payments in a similar way. After the charge is successful you can save the resulting info to your database.

The function:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const stripeApp = express();

stripeApp.use(bodyParser.json());

stripeApp.post('/order', (req, res) => {
  const { source } = req.body; // This is the token provided by your app

  return stripe.charges.create({...}) // the actual payment
});

exports.stripeAPI = functions.https.onRequest(stripeApp);
```

Have a took at Stripe's demo iOS app - its swift but it should still make sense in Obj-C world. https://github.com/stripe/stripe-connect-rocketrides/tree/master/ios/RocketRides.

Particularly https://github.com/stripe/stripe-connect-rocketrides/blob/master/ios/RocketRides/MainAPIClient.swift#L39

Comment: Thanks Dan, but I am a little bit new to the server stuff. Is that I could just upload the function code from your answer to my Firebase server, and my app will communicate with my Firebase server through MyAPIClient.swift ?

Comment: Basically yes! The HTTP function will give you a url endpoint that the APIClient in your app can make requests to.

Answer (score 0):

So the process that works for me is -

1) iOS provides card details to Stripe using native SDK

2) Stripe provides a token which you send it to your Firebase backend

`you could store it in stripeTokens/userId/yourToken`

3) Firebase cloud function then triggers a function and uses this token to create Stripe customer (See [saving for later](https://stripe.com/docs/saving-cards) and [Customer](https://stripe.com/docs/api#customers))

`you could store it in stripe_customers/userId/stripeCustomerId like your example`

4) Remember to remove `yourToken` because it's only valid once

5) finally you can use this `stripeCustomerId` to make payments

Important concept here is to create a customer and store in your backend for future payments.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks grgmo, Do we need to script a APIClient function (like the one in Stripe docs) when handling Stripe payment if I used Firebase as my backend?

Comment: and btw how to send the Stripe token to Firebase backend? My understanding is to "write" the token to the firebase database. But it seems not working since when I tried to "write" it, firebase told me it does not support the type of the token.

Comment: you just need a paid Firebase account because Stripe is external and you can use [stripe](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node) library to make stripe calls. Your token should look something like `tok_1234`

Comment: Is that I could only use custom integration of Stripe? Since I could not find where the token is generated inside standard integration of the Stripe document. And I am not able to write the token into my Firebase database directly, do you have any clue of it? Thank you again grgmo!

Comment: [this](https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/ios/custom#stpaddcardviewcontroller) should be all you need to get the token and you need to implement `submitTokenToBackend` method yourself to write to Firebase